# IN Keyword versus OR keyword

Tags: t-sql

Does it make much difference if I use in either of the following in a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE [Process Code] = 1 AND ([Material ID] = 'PLT' OR [Material ID] = 'BMI')

--or

WHERE [Process Code] =  1 AND [Material ID] IN ('PLT', 'BMI')
```

Would there be a time I would use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you've provided, they're doing the exact same thing (they will result in the same execution plan). However, with the latter syntax (besides being more terse) you can do this:

```
WHERE [Process Code] = 1 AND [Material ID] IN (SELECT ID FROM Material WHERE Type = @type)
```

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of a time I would use the first option.  The second option is much cleaner and more expressive.  And if it ever needs to be converted into a sub-select, it'll be easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` is just syntactic sugar for a bunch of `OR's`.  `IN` is usually preferable because it's much easier to read: it does not repeat the variable name, and you don't have to think about whether `AND` or `OR` has the higher operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

The query execution plans are usually the same either way.  You might check your expressions for null (`ISNULL(@parm,'')` or `ISNULL([fieldname],'')`, etc.) before running a comparison.

Microsoft warns:

> Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared
>   to test_expression using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null
>   values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.